# extracting alt-text from image in pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, accessibility

I built a web scraper using crawl spider to find and download pdf's on a given website, I want to be be able to grab alt-text from an image in the pdf. But I can't seem to find a library that does that. I've tried fitz, mupdf, pdfminer (nd like 100 of its iterations) and still got nothing. Is this even possible? I've tried decompressing the pdf and still got nothing.

Comment: Do you mean acrobat API's?  Here is an example is a pdf I am talking https://www.microassist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/AccessibilityLitigation-MicroassistAccessibilityServices-20160711.pdf The image of the keyboard has a alt description, and i would like to grab it

Comment: Yeah what I am trying to do is find an image and see if it has alt text or not, but I am struggling to find a way to do that

Comment: Can preflight be automated?

Comment: and what are you using to see <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">A black keyboard with a disabled sign</rdf:li>

Comment: Yeah this will all be automated, and I couldn't get anything legible out of the pdf even with deflate/decompress

Comment: Hey, I have a similar problem where I want to iterate over pdf files we have locally and try to find out if the images in there have an alt text or not. Seems like I can only see Mat's part of the discussion here, so I wondered if you found any solution? Currently using fitz, and pymupdf but it doesn't seem to do the trick?